# php file that checks timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to check whether my arduino device is still connected to the database from the android device. therefore, i thought that device should update in database 'last connected' with the timestamp whenever it connects. then the php file on a server checks that timestamp and if the timestamp hasn't changed within 10 seconds it should mark the device in database as disconnected.

i have no clue how to create such php file since i never had experience with it. can anyone tell me if that's even possible to do? and if so how should i approach it?

thanks.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it is also unnecessary. Just query the last connection time from your android device and do the check there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It can be done.(PHP)You need to connect to your database using mysql or mysqli connection.Then you can write queries to check whether timestamp was updated or not in last 10 seconds ,if not you can write script in php to update the database as disconnected.